# phonegap-cordova - javascript , Hebrew value of strings not encoded correctly

Tags: javascript, string, cordova, hebrew

Given the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>PhoneGap Application</title>
<script type = "text/javascript"  src = "cordova.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript" charset = "utf-8">
  
  function onBodyLoad() {
    
   alert("שלום");
  }
   
  </script>
</head>
<body onload = "onBodyLoad()" >
  
</body>
</html>
```

I run this code as a phonegap app on my galaxy note 2 , but the result alert content is a gibrish code something like "OoO#^"
i added link to screenshot-
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5juxri80o3qzsl/tempFileForShare.jpg?dl=0
thx.

i tried to open this page in ordinary browser and it's opened correctly.
so apparently the problem related to cordova.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is look like encoding problem.
try to add this after head tag.

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```